# How do I know how to appropriately use a method to access some variable/dataset?

Tags: python, sqlite, import, data-science

Intermediate Python learner here.

I'm going through a coding class in Python for Data Science, specifically to learn how to import datasets right now. A common problem I'm having (which I'll show in the example below) is that I'll be told to use a method like "table_names()" on some variable like "engine."

The mistake I'm commonly making is not knowing whether this means my code should be this:

```
engine.table_names()
```

Or this:

```
table_names(engine)
```

Depending on the situation, it seems like either of these options seem possible.

Is there a way to immediately know that the correct answer is this in this context?:

engine.table_names()

Basically, I've learned to do a lot of different things, but this is the kind of thing that is still going over my head. I'm not even sure how to correctly ask my question here so hopefully someone understands what I'm asking.

Here's the exercise in full:

> Import the function create_engine from the module sqlalchemy.
>
> Create an engine to connect to the SQLite database 'Chinook.sqlite'
>   and assign it to engine.
>
> Using the method table_names() on the engine engine, assign the table
>   names of 'Chinook.sqlite' to the variable table_names.
>
> Print the object table_names to the shell.

Here's the correct code:

```
# Import necessary module
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create engine: engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Chinook.sqlite')

# Save the table names to a list: table_names
table_names = engine.table_names()

# Print the table names to the shell
print(table_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the distinction is made between methods and functions. `engine.table_names()` is a method; `table_names(engine)` would be a function.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: But what about when there is something in the parentheses after table_names(). I guess I would call this an argument then, and in that context the table_names('something here') is also a function here then?